# Healthcheck for console app in Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, console-application

I have console app which packed in docker container.
It is just simple .NET6.0 console app

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var configuration = builder.Build();

var baseAddress = configuration.GetValue<string>("BASE_ADDRESS");

Console.WriteLine($"Hello, World! {baseAddress}");
```

What is best practice to healthcheck this console  application.

If it was web app i can add endpoint \health.
But i have console application. What can i do in this case ?

Comment: what do you mean by console app? how do you run the app?

Comment: I edited my post. It is just simple .NET6.0 console app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Powershell script in the absence of a health check endpoint.

For Example :

create a health healthcheck.sh:

```
pgrep -f "your_application_executable" > /dev/null
```

Use the copy health check command in the docker file

```
COPY healthcheck.sh /app 

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=10s --start-period=5s --retries=3 CMD ["./healthcheck.sh"]
```

Then build the docker image :

```
docker build -t your_image_name .
docker run -d --name your_container_name your_image_name
```

Use docker inspect to check application health :

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health.Status}}' your_container_name
```